# Spatial differentiation of unit vectors

Tags: differential-geometry, tensor-calculus

I am reading a book that is related to the dynamics of meteorology and I had a question from that book.

The authors have an equation that is the velocity tensor in spherical polar coordinates

$$ \nabla \mathbf v = \left(\mathbf e_\lambda {1 \over r \cos\phi} {\partial \over\partial \lambda} + \mathbf e_\phi {1 \over r} {\partial \over\partial \phi} + \mathbf e_r {\partial \over\partial r}\right) (u \mathbf e_\lambda + v \mathbf e_\phi + w \mathbf e_r)  $$

Here
  $$ u = r \space \cos \lambda \space {d \lambda\over dt}, v = r \space {d \phi\over dt} , w =  {dr\over dt} $$

So the question is related to the spatial differentiation of the unit vectors on the right hand side i.e the spatial derivatives of $$ \mathbf e_\lambda,\mathbf e_\phi,\mathbf e_r  $$ with respect to $$ \lambda,\phi , r $$

In other words

$$   {\partial e_\lambda\over\partial \lambda},{\partial e_\phi\over\partial \phi},{\partial e_r\over\partial r} $$ and other cross terms

In the book the authors are using [Christoffel symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christoffel_symbols) (or covariant differentiation) to do the spatial differentiation of the unit vectors as shown here

$$ {\partial \mathbf e_i\over \partial q_j  } = {\mathbf e_i\over \sqrt g_{ii}}{\partial \sqrt g_{jj}\over \partial q_i} - \delta^j_i {\mathbf e_n\over \sqrt g_{nn}}{\partial \sqrt g_{ii}\over \partial q^n}$$

Here $$q_i,q_j$$ are the individual coordinates i.e. $$\lambda,\phi,r $$

and while I do not mind using that technique to spatially differentiate the three unit vectors my question is whether there is an alternative way of arriving at that conclusion by using an approach such as differential forms or some other technique. While I would appreciate a full answer I would be satisfied with a link or a clue to help me with this question. Please keep in mind that I am not a trained mathematician.

Comment: Differential forms would certainly help, for one thing they give an invariant expression for the gradient.

Comment: @MoziburUllah - please feel free to go ahead and write an answer showing how it can be done.

Comment: thanks for the invite; but I made it a comment because I didn't feel like writing out a full answer; perhaps later, when I have some time.

Comment: You seek the result for spherical coordinates only?

Comment: @LucJ.Bourhis - As a start. If you can generalize for all go ahead.